# Help With Make Html Function

Tags: php, html, function

this is my first function in PHP Here is the code

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
.tright 
{
float:right;
margin:5px;
}
.tleft 
{
float:left;
margin:5px;
}
</style>
 </head><body>
<?php
$fullstring = '[p1]{{15em}}((tleft))
\\Biography//
[[Name==My Name]]
[[Fathers Name==My Father Name]]
[[Mothers Name==My Mother Name]]
[[Date Of Birth==My Date Of Birth]]

[/p1][p1]{{15em}}((tright))
\\Biography//
[[Name==My Name]]
[[Fathers Name==My Father Name]]
[[Mothers Name==My Mother Name]]
[[Date Of Birth==My Date Of Birth]]

[/p1]';


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr( $string,$ini,$len);
}
function Make_html($texttoprase){
//$parsed = get_string_between($texttoprase, "[p1]", "[/p1]");
$mywidth = get_string_between($texttoprase, "{{", "}}");
//replacing width variables
$texttoprase = str_replace("{{","",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("}}","",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace($mywidth,"",$texttoprase);
//getiing class for table
$myclass = get_string_between($texttoprase, "((", "))");
//replacing class variables
$texttoprase = str_replace("((","",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("))","",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace($myclass,"",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("[[","<tr><th scope=\"row\" style=\"text-align:left;\">",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("==","</th><td>",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("]]","</td></tr>",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("\\","<tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align:center;\">",$texttoprase);
$texttoprase = str_replace("//","</td></tr>",$texttoprase);
return "<div class=\"" . $myclass . "\"><table style=\"width: " . $mywidth . ";\" cellspacing=\"5\"><tbody>" . $texttoprase . "</tbody></table></div>";
}
$texttofind = get_string_between($fullstring, "[p1]", "[/p1]");
$textToReplace =  Make_html($texttofind) ;
$fullstring = str_replace("[p1]" . $texttofind . "[/p1]", $textToReplace ,$fullstring);
echo $fullstring;
?></body></html>
```

it make html on first occurence of [p1]/[p1] but how to make for the second any help or idea ?

Comment: you'd have a much easier time if you used a HTML parser.

Comment: You chose one of the most complicated things, you better learn something more simple.

Comment: thanks but it is not my answer

Comment: Did you by chance skip the code formatting chapter?

Answer (score 2):

This is going to return the first code inside the first occurrence. Modify the array index of the **$content** array to get other ones.

```
preg_match("|[p1](.+)[/p1]|si", $original_code, $content); 
echo $content[1];
```

Also to replace it with your html, replace the entire occurrence, starting from **[p1]** and ending with **[/p1]** with your html whatever function. To do that you will need preg_replace() and a regex (regular expression) which matches the everything inside including the **[p1]** tags. -->

```
preg_replace('#([[p1])(.*)([\p1]])#', makeHTML(), $original_code, $limit_changes);
```

The replacement code should look like this:

```
preg_match("|[p1](.+)[/p1]|si", $original_code, $content); 

for( $i=1; $i<=count($content); $i++){
    echo $content[$i]; //This is the code between the tags
    preg_replace('#([[p1])(.*)([\p1]])#', makeHTML($content[$i]), $original_code, 1);
}
```

**$original_code** is a string with the code which you need to replace.

**$content** is an array with the code between the [p1] tags

I assume that the parameter to the makeHTML function should be the code between the [p1] tags.

That should do it. ;) Vote for my answer!

Comment: Your problem is solved. I think. Good luck! If you have any more questions, ask.

Comment: thanks please define these $text_html=? $content=? $your_search_subject= ?

Comment: $content is an array which contains the code between the [p1] tags. $text_html is the variable with the original html or whatever code you are replacing. $your_search_subject should be the same as $text_html. I forgot to change the name.

Comment: its giving this `1]{{15em}}((tleft)) \Biography// [[Name==My Name]] [[Fathers Name==My Father Name]] [[Mothers Name==My Mother Name]] [[Date Of Birth==My Date Of Birth]] [/p1] [p1]{{15em}}((tright)) \Biography// [[Name==My Name]] [[Fathers Name==My Father Name]] [[Mothers Name==My Mother Name]] [[Date Of Birth==My Date Of Birth]] [/p
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '+' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 71

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '+' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 71`

Comment: I will make a change in the above code in several minutes. I will tell you when ready.

Comment: The preg_replace regex should look like this #([[p1])(.*)([\p1]])# .

Comment: @Itehno you should use `preg_callback()` for this type of complex actions.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it isn't that complex. It isn't more than a line of code. And as far as I know, this should work faster.

Comment: @Itehnological Disexisting: I don't appreciate the snide comment you left me on your deleted "answer", but thanks for removing it. Hope you understand how the site works a little bit more. Good luck with this catastrophe of a question.

Comment: ops error , `1]{{15em}}((tleft)) \Biography// [[Name==My Name]] [[Fathers Name==My Father Name]] [[Mothers Name==My Mother Name]] [[Date Of Birth==My Date Of Birth]] [/p1] [p1]{{15em}}((tright)) \Biography// [[Name==My Name]] [[Fathers Name==My Father Name]] [[Mothers Name==My Mother Name]] [[Date Of Birth==My Date Of Birth]] [/p
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p at offset 15 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 71

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unknown property name.....`

Comment: I googled that error and I might had wrote something in cyrillic in the regular expression which might have caused the problem. Try rewriting the regex. Honestly I am not a regex expert that is my weak side and probably you should ask someone else about that regex. Sorry, but my knowledge ends here.